# Why is "f" in a singular replaced with "v" in its plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

For example, "wife" is "wives" in plural, as is knife, strife, etc. What's the reason and/or etymology behind this?

Comment: +1 @Mark Richman: Just wondering, how did this question come up for you? Meaning what was the content that led you to ask it.

Comment: Oddly, we were discussing the similar pronunciations of "b" and "v" in many Spanish accents.

Comment: An interesting anecdote about this historical fact is that of course the "proper" plurals of "elf" and "dwarf" are "elfs" and "dwarfs" in modern English. Tolkien felt that both words ought to have more of an "ancient" feel to them in his fictional world, so he deliberately chose "elves" and "dwarves".  In one of his letters he takes to task the ignorant copy editors who attempted to change them back.

Comment: @EricLippert No, that’s not true.  Tolkien made ***dwarves*** match *elves*, and *elves* was already the standard plural. Thanks to Tolkien, the *dwarves* form is now at least as common as the *dwarfs* form.

Answer (score 9):

This is a throwback to Old English. The "f" would be pronounced like a "v" if it was between two vowels.

For example, the word for heaven was *heofon* and would have been pronounced something like "hayovon" (Sorry, no IPA).

Here's some information from an [article on English plurals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural):

> In Old and Middle English voiceless fricatives /f/, /θ/ mutated to voiced fricatives before a voiced ending.[6] In some words this voicing survives in the modern English plural. In the case of /f/ changing to /v/, the mutation is indicated in the orthography as well; also, a silent e is added in this case if the singular does not already end with -e:

[image]

(Adding screen snap here because the markdown here doesn't do tables easily.)

Comment: The second part (quoted from the article), answers the question. The first part, about orthography, does not, since the sound change happened before most people were literate.

Comment: Note that this happened some with /s/, e.g. "is" is pronounced /iz/, and "louse" = /laws/ -> "lousy" = /lawzij/.

Comment: @Colin Fine: There is a huge difference between "before most people were literate" and "before *anyone* was literate".  Unless it is the latter then it is certainly relevant — why wouldn't it be?  We see that the word began to be written down before the mutation occurred, and after it did, the word ultimately came to be spelled with a "v".  It is in the context of being between two vowels, thus illustrating that this was more widespread in English during this time period than just a few plurals.

Comment: A summary of the second part as I understand it: *F* doesn't transition well into *S*. Try saying "knifes" out loud. Either it felt awkward, or you pronounced the *F* more like a *V*.

Comment: Note: The NHL team in Toronto is correctly called the "Maple Leafs".

Comment: @Stuart: No, [fs] is just as easy to articulate as [vz]. It may not sound or feel as good to you, but it is the same mouth-shape, so I'd wager it's only because [fs] is less common. Besides, you don't have trouble with *skiffs*, or even *knifes* the third-person singular of *to knife*.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: *skiffs* *is* uncomfortable, relative to to *skivs*. *Knifes* is easier to articulate as a third-person present tense, but there it's pronounced more as [fz].

Comment: @Robusto: I think we are interpreting the question differently. I thought the question was about why the sound /v/ was substituted for the sound /f/: the answer is purely phonological, and has nothing to do with spelling. You took it to be a question about spelling. But actually, I still think your comments about spelling are beside the point: the case of "mouth/mouths" does require some comment, because the change of sound is not acknowledged in the spelling. In the case of "wife/wives" the different sound is spelt regularly, so I don't see a need to bring in OE spelling conventions.

Comment: @Stuart: No, it's got little or nothing to do with the 's': /fs/ and /vz/ are both natural for English speakers. It's because the 'e' was pronounced in Old and Middle English.

Comment: @Colin Fine: You're entitled to your opinion. I disagree, both with your characterization of my answer and the conclusions you draw.

Comment: Also, the plural of unvoiced *house* is the voiced *houses*. Unvoiced fricatives voice(d) in in the plural.