# Why is there no consistency in the plural forms of words ending on an "f" (e.g. safe, roof, dwarf, etc.)?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The plural form of *leaf* is *leaves*, although according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leaf) *leafs* is also correct. *Dwarf* can be pluralized as either *dwarfs* or *dwarves*. Conversely, the words *roof* and *safe* are pluralized as *roofs* and *safes*.

Is there any logic underpinning these variations? Is there a historical trend where words that were previously pluralized as *-ves* are now being increasingly pluralized as *-fs*?

Comment: Both *roofs* and *rooves* are perfectly acceptable alternatives in British English, as are *hoofs, hooves*. As [often homophobic] slang, I've seen *pooves* as well as *poofs*. But I think there's always a slow steady tendency for the irregular *(-ves)* forms to be displaced in favour of consistency with other plurals.

Comment: A related question about the origin of the voiced '-ves' can be found [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29376/why-is-f-in-a-singular-replaced-with-v-in-its-plural) (with interesting answer)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for the additional examples, and for enlightening me that "hoofs" is actually a valid form.

Comment: @ Ptriek: Thanks Ptriek, that was an interesting read. Both that answer and Barry's answer below point towards a phonological cause for the "-ves" ending.

Comment: Related: [Why is *f* in a singular replaced with *v* in its plural](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29376/why-is-f-in-a-singular-replaced-with-v-in-its-plural/29382#29382)

Comment: Thanks for the link Robusto. Ptriek had already linked to the topic before you did but without writing out the topic title. Your answer there made for an interesting read.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think "pooves" might not be a great example because the *singular* can also be "poove": http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poove

Comment: @alcas: I don't think I've *ever* heard *"poove"* in my life, so I don't know I'd give thefreedictionary much credibility on that entry. The only example of [he's a poove](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he's+a+poove%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) I can find in print seems to be written by William S. Burroughs (American), but I'd have thought it's not particulary an American usage anyway. The US version is "fag", but that's what we Brits smoke.

Comment: It seems strange to me that Merriam Webster records the "leafs" forms without comment–it strikes me as actually incorrect; although it's certainly possible as a form produced "in the wild," I don't believe anyone would retain it if they noticed it while proof-reading. The only context where I've heard other sources mention it is as the prescriptively correct plural in "Toronto Maple Leafs," and Google Ngram Viewer seems to indicate that "leafs" is on a totally different scale from "leaves" in terms of frequency.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, the *f*->*v* shift can be traced back to Old English, where *v* wasn't its own letter, but merely an allophone of *f*.  The */v/* pronunciation was used when it was placed between vowels or voiced consonants, and the */f/* pronunciation was used otherwise.

So the declination from *wīf* to *wīfes* meant that the actual pronunciation of the *f* went from */f/* to */v/* (much like today today), because it became positioned between two voiced vowels (I should point out, in OE *wīfes* was a two-syllable word [wiːvɛs]).

Now, over time, a few things happened:

- *V* became its own phoneme and began to be represented in the orthography of English
- English became less inflected
- We stopped pronouncing the last syllable

So we have a couple competing forces:

- With the *v* sound now entrenched in the spelling of many words, the idea of the *f->ves* for pluralization became a "rule" and was carried on and used by analogy when forming related/similar words.
- However, with the lack of a vowel sound in the final syllable, there was no longer a need to force the voicing of the labial fricative, leaving us with two viable pronunciations/spellings: the unvoiced pair *[fs]* (-fs) or the voiced pair *[vz]* (-ves)

Now, I can't find a good source for determining which word used which one, so treat the following as my own supposition:

My expectation then is that when a particular word entered the lexicon would greatly influence which option is chosen.  Words entering in Old and Middle English (and words derived from or related to them) would be much more likely to use the *-ves* option, while words entering later, particularly if they enter as loanwords from a Romance language, etc. would prefer the more regular *-fs*.

Additionally, now that there's no phonetic requirement to voice the consonant, we're seeing linguistic regularization kicking in, slowly pushing the *-ves* pluralization out in favor of the more regular *-fs* option.  So forms like *rooves* / *hooves* start to give way to *roofs* / *hoofs* and depending on where they are in that process, you see that one form may be preferred over another, or they may both be equally viable.

Answer (score 6):

Nouns ending in an unvoiced consonant will normally form their plural with the sound /s/, (*streets*) while those ending in a voiced consonant or vowel will normally do so with the sound /z/ (*roads, seas*). Those ending in certain other sounds form their plurals with /ɪz/. So, from *roof* and *safe* we’d expect /s/, as heard and spelt in *roofs* and *safes*. From *leaf* and *dwarf* we’d expect *leafs* and *dwarfs* which is what we also get. But, as you say, we also get *leaves* and *dwarves*, with the terminal consonant /z/ rather than /s/.

It seems as if the long vowels in each of those two words, /ɪ:/ in *leaf* and /ɔ:/ in *dwarf*, can override the unvoiced  consonants, /f/ in each case. That doesn’t happen with *safe* because the middle sound is the diphthong /eɪ/ rather than a long vowel. On the other hand, there is a long vowel, /u:/, in *roof*, and the plural can be realised as /ru:vz/ as well as /ru:fs/ and it is also sometimes spelt as *rooves*. But I must add the caution that I am not a phonetician and I am happy to be told by those with expertise in the area that I am wrong.

There is a distinction to be made between *dwarf*, an unusually short person, and *dwarf*, the creature of myth, folklore and film. However, the former long precedes the latter, which, in spite of claims to the contrary, Tolkien did not invent and which has its plural form recorded both as *dwarfs* and *dwarves*. The OED gives only *dwarfs* as the plural in its note on forms, and that is how we must spell it in other than Snow White and Middle Earth contexts, but I would guess that the pronunciation /dwɔːvz/ is not unknown elsewhere.

Comment: Interesting theory, Barry!

Comment: So Tolkien did, as both he and common belief have it, invent *dwarves*?

Comment: @TimLymington: Apparently not. Under the definition ‘One of a supposed race of diminutive beings, who figure in Teutonic and esp. Scandinavian mythology and folk-lore’, the OED has four citations, all of them predating Tolkien, with the earliest from 1770.

Comment: My point is that (in all but one of the citations)they are *dwarfs*, and remained so up to both Disney and C S Lewis; it was the influence of JRRT that made them *dwarves*. Whatever you think of the origin, the distinction between 'dwarfs short people' and 'dwarves mythical creatures' is both noticeable and valuable.

Comment: @TimLymington: I once attended a lecture on 'Beowulf' by Tolkien, and great stuff it was, but I have read none of the books, so I'm really in no position to judge. If it's important to distinguish between very short people and the mythical creatures, is it unimportant to distinguish between single members of each set?

Comment: Tolkien knew exactly what he was doing: "The form *dwarves* is used, although the dictionaries tell us that the plural of *dwarf* is *dwarfs*. It should be *dwarrows* (or *dwerrows*) if singular and plural had each gone its own way down the years, as have *man* and *men* or *goose* and *geese*. But we no longer speak of a dwarf as often as we do of a man, or even of a goose, and memories have not been fresh enough among Men to keep hold of a special plural [...] But in the Third Age something of their old character and power is still glimpsed." -*LOTR*, III, App.F

Comment: @StoneyB If you look hard enough, you can find older reference to *dwarves*.  But apart from a short :) run on them in the early 19th century, these are comparatively rare. The earliest I’ve turned up is an index entry  on “Jesters and dwarves” from in *Of the Russe Commonwealth*, published in 1591.  But it is quite natural to change an unvoiced final consonant into its voiced version when make a plural out of it, includes unvoiced *s* and *th* becomes voiced.  Consider *house* > *houses*.  This is just part of the phonology of the plural as it used to be. We no longer always observe it today.

Comment: I don't think your theory about long vowels having a different effect from diphthongs is correct. We also have the words *staves,* which was historically the plural of *staff* and which has the diphthong /eɪ/; *wife-wives* and *life-lives,* which have the diphthong /aɪ/; and *loaf-loaves,* which has the diphthong /oʊ/. On the other hand, there are words with long vowels that don't get v like *beliefs, briefs, chiefs, reliefs, fiefs.*

Answer (score 2):

Two additions to the above:

1) Anglo-saxon may be related to old Dutch from Freisland. The Dutch form of the plural generally changes a final -*f* to -*ven* as in the Dutch word for 'dove': *duif/duiven*. This may be only a curiosity, however, because the Dutch 'v' sound is far closer to the Engish 'f', and Dutch spelling has been regularized a few times. However, I think it is the root of many English irregular forms.

2) There is a 'Note on the Text' in my Harper Collins (1991) 'The Fellowship of the Ring, J.R.R. Tolkien. The 'Note' is signed by Douglas A. Anderson (April 1993), and states that:

> "Tolkien experienced what became for him a continual problem: printer's errors and compositor's mistakes, including well-intentioned 'corrections' of his sometimes idiosyncratic usage. These 'corrections' include the altering of dwarves to dwarfs, elvish to elfish,...and ('worst of all' to Tolkien) elven to elfin."

Comment: English is definitely closely related to Dutch. However, that doesn't mean that Dutch is the "root" of English.

Answer (score 0):

The correct spelling of *dwarf* in our world is *dwarf* and the plural is *dwarfs*.

In Middle-earth they are called *dwarves* - this was invented by Tolkien based on the original Old English spelling of *dwarf* and Anglo-Saxon grammar for plurals.

Tolkien was a professor of English and an expert on Old English and Anglo-Saxon; many of the names and words in his works are based on these languages.

Comment: ps the distinction is important: dwarfs are the short people who insist on being called 'person of restricted growth', dwarves carry battle axes and cut you off at the knees when they aren't making magic rings

Comment: I don't believe the distinction is quite so clear-cut: Snow White's companions were magical beings rather than just vertically challenged, and the film is *Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs*.