# Plural spelling of words ending with 'f'?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography

Why is it that in the plural spelling of many nouns (thief, leaf, life, knife, etc) with an ending consonant of 'f', the 'f' is replaced with a 'v' while other words such as 'chief' (chef, handkerchief) retain the 'f'?

Comment: *Handkerchieves* is also an acceptable spelling

Comment: Not just possible duplicate. The answer is at https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51692/15299

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any definitive answer for this, but I did notice something when looking at the etymology of these words in the Oxford Dictionaries:

> [Thief](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thief):
>   Old English thiof, theof, of Germanic origin; related to
>   Dutch dief and German Dieb, also to theft.
>   [Leaf](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leaf):
>   Old English leaf, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch loof and German Laub.
>   [Knife](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/knife):
>   Late Old English cnif, from Old Norse knífr, of Germanic origin.
>   [Life](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/life):
>   Old English lif, of Germanic origin; related
>   to Dutch lijf, German Leib ‘body’, also to live.
>
> [Chief](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chief):
>   Middle English: from Old French chief, chef, based on
>   Latin caput ‘head’.
>   [Chef](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chef):
>   Early 19th century: French, literally ‘head’.
>   [Handkerchief](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/handkerchief):
>   Mid 16th century: from hand + kerchief.
>   [Kerchief](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kerchief):
>   Middle English kerchef, from Old French cuevrechief, from couvrir ‘to cover’ + chief ‘head’.

So, it sure looks to me like the words that come from French (*Chief*, *Chef*, and *Kerchief*) do *not* change the *F* to a *V* while the words of Germanic origin (*Thief*, *Leaf*, *Knife*, and *Life*) do.

Comment: All true, as far as it goes. But not all Germanic words do this. There's a long story. Details nicely provided here https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51692/15299